# using React router with history.js via CDN

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm working on a project that is using react added into a static HTML page, but I can't get react router to work properly. I keep getting the following error from HashRouter:

```
index.tsx:177 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createHashHistory')
```

Here are the CDN links I'm using for my project:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/6.2.1/react-router.development.js" integrity="sha512-x/vwJ8OCwhBaXS1SCWX2WiYvvIO6RKbMMn/ZlRP4CPhpM7SnaladKEnQgcejrA7Ep0RDMaxjB98VvOOlDuhm9Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/6.2.1/react-router-dom.development.js" integrity="sha512-uAx4/XQlub/EIs2IQ1Tq/kgkJF+GRNTocKZBDSSTSBjCZmfkvCUIQ+D9QoWlXXvgEkBCbGAaj7Ay+o/3EM9uuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/history/5.2.0/history.development.js" integrity="sha512-He5zdxgskQISMuGJzMzSF7ndvQ2L9ffBpA9tkBIJwTTFnp2bBUVhND8JLvbLxGcLa5ul7wB/VijK7Lw4gkWMjA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

My router imports in my App component:

```
// Router
const Router = ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter;
const { createHashHistory } = history;
const Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;
const Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link;
```

Router wrapped around my component:

```
<Router history={createHashHistory}>
  <MyAccount customerInfo={customerInfo}/>
</Router>
```

EDIT: Additional info about the HashRouter exception:

Seems to crash on this line: `historyRef.current = createHashHistory({ window });`

```
export function HashRouter({ basename, children, window }: HashRouterProps) {
  let historyRef = React.useRef<HashHistory>();
  if (historyRef.current == null) {
    historyRef.current = createHashHistory({ window });
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I can't find much info on getting this type of setup to work.

Comment: I'm looking into the history CDN part, but otherwise I don't think this will quite this simply. The higher-level routers exported in `react-router-dom` v6 don't take a `history` object as a prop. See [HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#hashrouter). You'll need to create a custom router using the low-level [`Router`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#router) first. It could just be that you need to reference a `History` instead of `history`, i.e. something like `const { createHashHistory } = History;` or `const createHashHistory = History.createHashHistory;`.

Comment: I get the same exception when changing 'history' to 'History', and when I remove the history prop from my HashRouter I still get the error as well.

I have added some more info about the exception above.

Comment: Ok, looks like latest available for you on cdnjs is v5.1.0 (https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/tree/master/ajax/libs/history). Try switching to `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/history/5.1.0/history.development.js" integrity="sha512-..." ...></script>`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like latest available for you on cdnjs is v5.1.0 (https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/tree/master/ajax/libs/history).

Try switching to v5.1.0 from v5.2.0:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/history/5.1.0/history.development.js" integrity="sha512-..." ...></script>
```

To address my first comment regarding the router see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69953377/react-router-v6-how-to-use-navigate-redirection-in-axios-interceptor/70012117#70012117) for creating a custom hash router.

```
// Router
const Router = ReactRouterDOM.Router; // <-- low-level router!!
const { createHashHistory } = history;
const Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;
const Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link;

const CustomRouter = ({ history, ...props }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    action: history.action,
    location: history.location
  });

  useLayoutEffect(() => history.listen(setState), [history]);

  return (
    <Router
      {...props}
      location={state.location}
      navigationType={state.action}
      navigator={history}
    />
  );
};
```

...

```
const history = createHashHistory();
```

...

```
<CustomRouter history={createHashHistory}>
  <MyAccount customerInfo={customerInfo}/>
</CustomRouter>
```

Comment: This looks promising, but i'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createHashHistory')` history.createHashHistory doesn't seem to exist. Actually, in the debugger `const { createHashHistory } = history;` history is undefined.

Comment: @boostedd And if you try `History` here now, does it resolve the undefined issue?

Comment: That did not work, however I did find that this references the correct function: `const { createHashHistory } = window.HistoryLibrary;`

I am using <script src="https://unpkg.com/history/umd/history.production.min.js"></script> and I also tried the CDN link you posted with the same results.

I'm getting the same exact exception as the original post.

Comment: Here is the value of `const history = createHashHistory();`
`
{
    "action": "POP",
    "location": {
        "pathname": "/",
        "search": "",
        "hash": "",
        "state": null,
        "key": "default"
    }
}`

Comment: Thank you for the help! I changed out my CDN links to use react-router-dom v5.2.1 instead and everything is working now, the browser is showing the hashrouter behavior. The component wrapped in the router is not rendering, but that is a different issue since the rest of the applications components outside the router load fine.

Comment: @boostedd Great! Are you saying that your `MyAccount` component specifically isn't rendering? I updated my answer to indicate you should import/use the low-level base `Router` component for the custom router since you are using a custom history object. Oh, just caught what you said about switching to RRDv5, yeah, the `HashRouter` from that version should work with a `history` prop. Can you still clarify the rendering issue?

Comment: That is correct, `MyAccount` is rendering now with 

`<CustomRouter history={history}>
  <MyAccount customerInfo={customerInfo}/>
 </CustomRouter>`

`const { createHashHistory } = window.HistoryLibrary;` was key since it wasn't referencing the module correctly. I am using your custom router still.