# Use of React router v6 history/Navigate in redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm trying to use history.push("/") from react router v6 to redirect when action is dispatched from redux store. When i use history it replaces the url but not the content ( component is not rendered )

I know we can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/connected-react-router but its not supporting v6 of react router.

Any thoughts how this can be achieved with custom router or any ref's ?

Any help much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70000286/8690857 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/70012117/8690857

Comment: Can you update your question to share what you've tried already? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese!! What you shared seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

there are some changes at v6, you can following :

// v5
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

**V5**

```
function MyButton() {
  let history = useHistory();
  function handleClick() {
    history.push('/home');
  };
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>;
};
```

**V6**

// v6
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

```
function MyButton() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  function handleClick() {
    navigate('/home');
  };
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>;
};
```

and

**V5**

```
// v5
history.push('/home');
history.replace('/home');
history.push('/home', {state: state});
```

**V6**

```
// v6
navigate('/home');
navigate('/home', {replace: true});
navigate('/home', {state: state});
```

Comment: This isn't very useful at all in the context of the question, which is in a redux reducer and NOT in a functional component