# Alternative of the old CreateBrowserHistory() function in React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to push a new route in history of my app, and as you know, the `UseHistory()` hook and `CreateBrowserHistory()` function (to create a user-defined history) have been removed from new version of 6. I know that I can use `UseNavigate` hook and do this work with `Navigate()` function, but this hook cannot be called at the top level and must be called in a React function component. Codes below show how we could do this with React Router version 5.1:

Passing the `history` to the parent component and exporting the same `history` object for using it anywhere in Application:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history' // which comes along with React-Router

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement)
root.render(
    <Router history={history}>
        <App />
    </Router>
)
```

Using the exported `history` object in another place of Application at the top level:

```
switch (status) {
    case 404:
        history.push('/not-found');
        break
```

if I want to do this at the top level in the new version of 6, What do you recommend?

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69953377/react-router-v6-how-to-use-navigate-redirection-in-axios-interceptor/70012117#70012117 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69871987/react-router-v6-navigate-outside-of-components/70000286#70000286

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React router v6 how to use \`navigate\` redirection in axios interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69953377/react-router-v6-how-to-use-navigate-redirection-in-axios-interceptor)

Comment: @jonrsharpe actually no

Comment: Then [edit] the question to reflect what you've learned from those resources and what problem you're still facing.