# History.push not working in axios interceptors (the url change but the component dosen't change)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router-dom, interceptor

When my refresh token expires i will be pushed back to the login page, i have seen all the examples and tried to apply but it didn't work for me, i used it again with react-router-dom v6

index.js

```
  <Provider store={store}  >
    <BrowserRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
```

App.js

```
 <div className="App" >
  <LoadingPage />
  <FetchProfile />
  <AlertMessages />

  <Routes >
    <Route path="/" element={<MainLayout />}>
      <Route path="/users" element={<UsersPage />} />
      <Route path="/agent" element={<AgentPage />} />
      <Route path="/server-database" element={<ServerDBPage />} />
      <Route path="/customers" element={<CustomersPage />} />
      <Route path="/agmdb" element={<AgmdbPage />} />
      <Route path="/profile" element={<ProfilePage />} />
      <Route path="/userlogs" element={<UserLogsPage />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/login" element={<LoginLayout />} />
  </Routes>
</div>
```

history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory()
export default history;
```

axios

```
axiosClient.interceptors.response.use((response) => {

    return handleResponse(response)

}, (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;

    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {

        if (isRefreshing) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                failedQueue.push({ resolve, reject })
            }).then(token => {
                originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
                return axiosClient.request(originalRequest);
            }).catch(err => {
                return Promise.reject(err);
            })
        }

        originalRequest._retry = true;
        isRefreshing = true;

        const refreshToken = LocalStorageService.getRefreshToken();

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/refreshtoken`, { refreshtoken: refreshToken }, {
                // headers: defaultHeader
            }).then((res) => {

                const { data } = res;
                // 1) put token to LocalStorage
                LocalStorageService.setToken(data.response);

                // 2) Change Authorization header
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + data.response.accessToken;
                originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + data.response.accessToken;

                processQueue(null, data.response.accessToken);

                // 3) return originalRequest object with Axios
                resolve(axiosClient.request(originalRequest));

            })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                    const { status, data } = err.response;

                    if (status === 401) {
                        history("/login")   
                    }
                    if (data && (data.error.code === "REFRESH_TOKEN_INVALID")) {
                        history("/login")   
                    }
                    processQueue(err, null);
                    reject(err);
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    isRefreshing = false
                })
        })
    }
    return Promise.reject(handleError(error));
});
```

when the token expires, it automatically converts the url to "https://url.com/login" but the component doesn't change

Comment: why dont you use the  `useNavigate` ?

Comment: See also [React router v6 how to use `navigate` redirection in axios interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69953377/8690857).