# Why won't my endpoint's data display on the browser on successful auth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I just don't understand why the user's name that's coming from my endpoint won't show up on the browser on successful auth (when user logs in successfully using their credentials).  When the user logs in, I want them to be greeted with a simple `Hello, *name*` but the `*name*` won't show up.  I'm successfully grabbing the name via `console.log(response.data[0].name);` so I know the name's definitely coming through based on what I see in the console.

I've tried too many ways to list in order to solve this issue but ran out of options.  I know it's something minuscule I'm overlooking but just can't spot what, I just need another pair of eyes to see what's wrong in my code.

How can I solve this?

Here's login component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            remember_me: true,
            name: '',
            logged_in_flag: false,
            access_token: null,
            auth: false
        }
        this.emailHandler = this.emailHandler.bind(this);
        this.passwordHandler = this.passwordHandler.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    emailHandler(e) {
        this.setState({
            email: e.target.value,
        });
    }

    passwordHandler(e) {
        this.setState({
            password: e.target.value,
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const user = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
            remember_me: this.state.remember_me
        }

        JSON.stringify(user);

        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }

        const { history } = this.props;

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login', user, {headers})
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data[0].name);
                console.log(response.data.access_token);
                let set_access_token = Cookies.set("access_token", response.data.access_token);
                this.setState({
                    logged_in_flag: true,
                    name: response.data[0].name,
                    access_token: set_access_token,
                    auth: true
                });
                Cookies.set("access_token", this.state.access_token);
                history.push('wall-of-fame');
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log("AXIOS ERROR!! " + error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {name, auth} = this.state;
        console.log(this.state.name);
        console.log(this.state.auth);
        if(auth) {
            console.log("ARE WE HERE");
            return(
                <Redirect to={{
                    pathname: "/wall-of-fame",
                    state: {name: name}
                }} />
            );
        }

        return(
            <div id="login">
                <div className="container">
                    <div id="login-row" className="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <div id="login-column" className="col-md-6">
                            <div id="login-box" className="col-md-12">
                                <form id="login-form" className="form" method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="email" className="text-info">Email:</label><br/>
                                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" className="form-control" onChange={this.emailHandler}/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="password" className="text-info">Password:</label><br/>
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" className="form-control" onChange={this.passwordHandler}/>
                                    </div>
                                    <Link to='/wall-of-fame'>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <input type="submit" name="submit" className="btn btn-info btn-md" value="Submit"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </Link>
                                    <Link to="/register">
                                        <div id="register-link" className="text-right">
                                            <a href="#" className="text-info">Register here</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </Link>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Here's Wall component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class Wall extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}!</h1>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Wall);
```

Here's App component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Switch, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login/Login';
import Wall from './components/Wall/Wall';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            auth: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // I'm not Unsure if I need to do anything here
        if(Cookies.get("access_token") !== null) {
            console.log("it's true!");
            this.setState({auth: true});
        } else {
            console.log("it's false");
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    <Route path="/wall-of-fame" component={Wall}/>
                </Switch>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: console.log("ARE WE HERE"); is this console is getting displayed ?

Comment: @pageNotfoUnd yep it is.

Comment: make a console for this.state.name in authSuccess it must be "" i guess

Answer (score 0):

You're using Routing, so you need to use routes and links.

This:

```
authSuccess(authenticated) {
        const {name} = this.state;

        if(authenticated) {
            console.log("ARE WE HERE");
            return(
                <Wall name={name}/>
            );
        }
        return <Login/>;
    }
```

Should navigate to `/wall-of-fame` instead of returning a component. Your render function isn't rendering the output of `authSuccess`, so it won't care what's being returned. You need to use `react-router`'s functions to navigate to the correct link.

Have a search for "React router, navigate after login" or something. You'll find good answers such as this question: [Navigate to page after authentication using React Router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432271/navigate-to-page-after-authentication-using-react-router-v4)

Comment: just updated my Login component.  may you please take a look.  It's still not showing name :(.

Comment: @cloudyday You need `withRouter` for your `Login` component, same as your `Wall` component. That's what passes the `history` to the `props`