# React Router v4 navigation programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

When I use react router with Redirect, Link or NavLink eveything is fine. But I need a function that navigates me to a route programmatically.

That is what I want :

```
if(a == 1){
    this.context.history.push("/")
}
else {
    this.context.history.push("/home");
}
```

As you see context history is not exists in react router v4 any more. I cannot write withroute in js code for navigation. Can anyone say me how to navigate directly in js code?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using  React Router's `browserHistory` ?

Comment: I am using react-router-dom i mean v4. I cannot ser any solution with it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically navigate using React router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The router will add a `history` to your props, you can use it like this:

`this.props.history.push('/mypath')`

Check this for more info: [Navigating Programatically in React-Router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894547/navigating-programatically-in-react-router-v4)

Comment: This only changes the URL, without really navigating