# React Router V4 (react-router-dom) navigate programatically deep in the tree

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I´ve checked [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894547/navigating-programmatically-in-react-router-v4) and although it gives several different solutions not of them seens to solve my problem.

Using react-router V4 I need to programatically navigate from components deep insider my tree that **will not** have access to router props passed (history, url, params, etc.). What is the most straightfoward way of doing it ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you get an error when trying `this.context.router.transitionTo` or `this.props.history.push`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any component in your tree, irrespective of its depth, can get access to the `history`, `location` and `match` props which are used by `react-router`. To do this you have to wrap the component in the `withRouter` HOC provided by `react-router`.

Code:

```
//other imports
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

//define component MyComponent here

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Inside MyComponent defined above, you can access the `history` prop and redirect to any new url by using `this.props.history.push(newURL);` You can find more information at https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: What about the options related to `shouldComponentUpdate`, like: `// This gets around shouldComponentUpdate
withRouter(connect(...)(MyComponent))

// This does not
connect(...)(withRouter(MyComponent))` - What are they used for ?

Comment: you should ask that to @ShubhamKhatri who answered that question. Or you can post another question. :)

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward way is to move history into separate file like so

`history.js`:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
const history = createHistory()
export default history
```

and then in any other component:

```
import history from 'path/to/history.js'

...
someFoo(){
  history.push({
    pathname: '/new/url',
  })
}
...
```

You also need to make sure you pass new history to your router to make it work

Comment: What do you mean by "You also need to make sure you pass new history to your router to make it work" I've tried this and the history changes but the component doesn't changed as it will if I I was using `Link`

Comment: That's probably because you have 2 instances of history. Most likely you need to reference the same history on your router, for example `import history from 'path/to/history.js' <ConnectedRouter history={history}>`